# Как добавить в архив папку, используя Zip4j и OutputStream

Tags: java, zip

Я пытаюсь добавить в архив папку вот так (в соответствии с документацией):

```
    //file - пустая папка, parametrs - обычный параметры, ничего важного
    zipStream.putNextEntry(file, parameters);

    if (file.isDirectory()) {
        //В документации написано, что, если файл является папкой,
        //нужно закрыть элемент
        zipStream.closeEntry();
    }
```

Но, в результате, программа засовывает мне в архив файл с названием папки :/.

---

Как добавить папку в архив?

Comment: Если без стримов, то, вроде, просто https://github.com/dmp/zip4j/blob/master/src/net/lingala/zip4j/examples/zip/AddFolder.java

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, я знаю, что без стримов просто... :)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, сейчас буду переписывать без стримов. Ничего уже придумать не могу...

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, я уже ненавижу эту библиотеку. Примеры не рабочие...

Comment: А чем являются эти `zipStream` и `file`?

Comment: @post_zeew, `zipStream` - `ZipOutputStream`, `file` - `File - директория`.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, кажется, победил..........

Comment: @bukashka101, не забудьте в ответ написать)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, да я вообще все без стримов сделал. Сейчас буду возиться с созданием нужных архивов и т.д. Лучше удалю вопрос.

Comment: Не, не надо удалять. Пусть будет лучше без стримов ответ чем вообще ответа не будет)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все-таки, не найдя ответа, я пришел к выводу, что лучше использовать архивирование без потоков.

Изначально я хотел получить полностью точный прогресс создания архива (суммировал размеры всех файлов, ну а дальше по формуле), но, увы, не нашел способа борьбы с папками. Методом хитрых маневров у меня вышло переварить и папки, и файлы, и, даже, подпапки в подпапках, но без точного прогресса создания (теперь две полосы: процент заархивированных папок, и процент архивации текущего файла).